# How to 'append' a mysql column onto another

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have built a search function within my website by utilizing the LIKE `mysqli` query.

I.e.

```
$contact = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE f_name LIKE '%$searching%' OR l_name LIKE '%$searching%'");
```

Lets say I have a contact

- f_name: bob
- l_name: chan

If I type 'bob' in my input field it will successfully find bob likewise if I type 'chan'.

What I want to be able to do is type 'bob chan' and have it locate the contact.

I assume there is some way to 'append' mysqli columns? Something like..

```
$contact = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE f_name.' '.l_name LIKE '%$searching%'");
```

What would be the correct syntax in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT(str1,str2,...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to join multiple values.

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE concat( f_name, ' ', l_name ) LIKE '%$searching%'
```

**Documentation Reference**:

> `CONCAT(str1,str2,...)`
>
> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form.
>
> `CONCAT()` returns NULL if any argument is NULL.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
>        'MySQL' 
> mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', NULL, 'QL');
>        NULL 
> mysql> SELECT CONCAT(14.3);
>        '14.3'
> ```
>
> For quoted strings, concatenation can be performed by placing the
>   strings next to each other:
>
> ```
>  mysql> SELECT 'My' 'S' 'QL';
>         'MySQL'
> ```

Comment: Would you happen to know a simple mysqli entry that would cover all possible individual search option concatenations? Allowing the user to type in for example 'fname,lastname,suburb' or 'suburb,lastname,firstname'. Basically covering any variation of entry the user may type without having to have to concat every possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The expression to do string concatenation in MySQL would use the `CONCAT` function, e.g.

```
  CONCAT(f_name,' ',l_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can concat the fields in the database, you will run into issues if you do it that way. As an example, say you search `bob chan` using `concat(f_name, ' ', l_name) LIKE %searching%`, you would not get `bobby chan` in your result set since `bob chan` is not in `bobby chan` (you have `by` in the middle).

A better option would be to split the search string: `$parts = explode(' ', $searching)`, then use your original filter of:

```
WHERE f_name LIKE '%$parts[0]%' OR l_name LIKE '%$parts[1]%'
```

As a side note, you will want to protect against injection by escaping the strings.

Comment: Excellent points. Prepared statements with bind placeholders are a good pattern for thwarting SQL injection.